# Make program quit based on user input

Tags: java, loops

I want my program to quit when I input "Q" or "q". However, the loop never finishes. Can you help me figure it out, please?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    char str ;
     
    do {
        System.out.println("Choose one of the following option : ");
        System.out.println("U or u - to convert SAR amount to USD");
        System.out.println("E or e - to convert SAR amount to EURO");
        System.out.println("Q or q - to quit");
        str = input.next().charAt(0);
     
        if (str == 'U' || str == 'u'  ) {
       
        }
        else if (str == 'E' || str == 'e'  ){
     
        }   
    } while( str != 'Q' || str != 'q' );
}
```

Comment: Your question was answered, but one thing you could do would be to wrap your input in Character.toLowerCase() or Character.toUpperCase() and you'll only have to check either capital or lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

`str != 'Q' || str != 'q'` is always `true`. Any given string is not equal to one or the other of these (or both). You want `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: You could also convert the input to uppercase with `str.toUpperCase()`. This will reduce the number of possibilities you need to consider.

Answer (score 1):

A nice structure to use would be the structure similar to the one recommended for getopt_long() in C but for Java obviously. Can read the man page here https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long

```
while(true)
{
    str = input.next().charAt(0);      
  
    if(str.toUpperString.equals('Q'))
    {
        break;
    }

    // In general if you want upper and lower case to do the same thing 
    //use toUpperString
    switch (str) {
        case 'U': 
        case 'u':
            // Do something
            break;
    
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            // Do something
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong input");    
            break;
    }

}
```

Another good solution to this problem, if you don't want to use the switch statement, is the loop-and-a-half.
https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Basic-JavaScript-and-Graphics/loop-and-a-half.html

The structure goes like this:

```
while(true)
{
    String token = Character.toUpperCase( input.next().charAt(0) );

    if(token.equals('A'))
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(token.equals('B'))
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(token.equals('Q'))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the program when you write Q or q. you can convert the input to any of the lower or uppercase.

```
str.toUpperCase();

 if (str == 'U'){
 }
 else if (str == 'E'){
 }   
   
 } while( str != 'Q');

}
```

**OR**

change the condition for checking Q or q.

```
while( str != 'Q' && str != 'q' );
```

for the above code snippet, the while loop will execute if str is not Q or q.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in); 
    char str ;
        do{
            System.out.println("Choose one of the following option : ");
            System.out.println("U or u - to convert SAR amount to USD");
            System.out.println("E or e - to convert SAR amount to EURO");
            System.out.println("Q or q - to quit");
            str = input.next().charAt(0);
       
            if (str == 'U' || str == 'u'){}
            else if (str == 'E' || str == 'e'){}   
           
           } while(str != 'Q' && str != 'q');  // change the condition from || to &&

           // Also close the input stream to avoided memery leakage 
           input.close();
    }
```